# IN vs. WITH: which is correct in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, prepositions

> He has started constructing meaningful sentences which require a lot of correction '**in**' grammar and spellings.

or

> He has started constructing meaningful sentences which require a lot of correction '**with**' grammar and spellings.

Comment: Sometimes simplification works better - "He has started constructing meaningful sentences which require a lot of grammar and spelling correction."

Answer (score 1):

**Quick summary**: You *should* say "correction(s) to" when describing tangible, countable changes, but "correction of" when describing the general act of correcting, but no one is likely to care if you mix it up.

---

Right away, we can rule out "corrections with." This has a different meaning: "with" introduces an object which is doing or aiding the corrections. For example, we can say "I made corrections with a pen," but should not say "I made corrections with spelling" (although this would still be easily understood).

The other choices are a little murkier. I've encountered "corrections of...", "corrections to..." and "corrections in..." in well-written literature. To my ear, "corrections to..." sounds the most correct, *but not by much*. Since English has no authoritative definition, we have to do a little more research.

---

First, we have to make a distinction between two subtly different meanings of "correction." The first meaning refers to the change itself. [From dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/correction):

> *noun* **1** something that is substituted or proposed for what is wrong or inaccurate; emendation.

We intend this meaning when we talk about *making a correction*. It is a *countable noun*: you can make 2 or 3 corrections, for example.

The second meaning refers to the action of making the change:

> *noun* **2** the act of correcting.

We intend this meaning when we talk about the general act of correction. It is an *uncountable* noun. For example, "vitamins can be prescribed for correction of nutrient deficiency."

In the OP sentence, the first meaning (**1**) is the sense intended.

---

Here are some example sentences listed at dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster. In each example I have marked which of the two above meanings (**1** or **2**) are being used, and I have also emphasized the preposition following *correction* in **bold**.

> - dictionary.com:
>
>   - He ordered his secretary to reimburse the fees and will issue a correction **to** his political funds reports. (**1**)
>   - Cases may arise in which a correction **of** the judgment thus formed may be necessary. (**2**)
> - Merriam-Webster:
>
>   - correction **of** (acidity / vision / etc.) (**2**)
>   - Restylane® Silk is for lip augmentation and for correction **of** perioral wrinkles in patients over the age of 21. (**2**)

---

We can also look at Ngrams, although we have to be careful to note that Google's search engine is not capable of differentiating between meanings **1** and **2** that we distinguished earlier.

**corrections to/of/in**:
[image: Ngrams for corrections X]

**correction to/of/in**:
[image: Ngrams for correction X]

The top graph uses the plural **corrections**, which limits the results to the *countable* form (meaning **1**). It clearly shows that **to** is the preferred preposition.

The bottom graph uses the singular form **correction**, which would include both meanings **1** and **2**. It clearly shows that **of** is the preferred preposition.

---

Taking all of this into account, it seems safe to infer that when speaking about tangible, *countable* corrections being made to something, the preferred form is **corrections to**:

> I made **corrections to** the spelling and grammar.

On the other hand, when talking about the general, *uncountable* act of correcting, the preferred form is **corrections of**:

> Vitamins can be prescribed for **correction of** nutrient deficiency.

Of course, I doubt many native speakers have ever taken the time to think about this, and I seriously doubt very many people would think twice whether you say "to," "in" or "of."

Answer (score 0):

Between your two example sentences both are understandable, but

> require a lot of correction**s** *with* grammar and spelling.

would probably be the more common usage. "A lot" implies many therefore plural *corrrections*.

> These are the corrections *with* your grammar and spelling.
>   These are the corrections *on* your grammar and spelling.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter.Just one clarification.. What if I meant correction as a verb rather than a noun? i.e. lot of correction to be done by the teacher and not the actual corrections (mistakes).

Comment: An Ngram comparison shows that *correction/s of* is vastly more popular than *correction on/with*.

Comment: I might say that it should be that they "require a lot of corrections *of* grammar and spelling", if this way of wording it is preferred.

Comment: @AanchalS That's not a verb (the verb is "correct"), that's an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the correct answer is in fact this:

> He has started constructing meaningful sentences which require a lot
>   of correction**s to** grammar and spelling.

Spelling should be singular even when referring to multiple instances of correction. *Correction* or *corrections* I don't think makes a lot of difference and works either way, *corrections* feels a little more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

"grammar and spelling[s]" describe what "correction" consists of, so it would "of".